# Clear particular field in a form when a particular field is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able to clear particular fields in the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#zip').on("input",function(){
       $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);

   })

    $('#city').on("change",function(){
       $('#zip').val("");
    })
})
```

and the following is the form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">

    <form name="providerSearch" id="PS" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
        <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                   <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                       <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>

        <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>---->
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
                <div class="form-group widthLanguage">


                <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                 <cfoutput query="Languages">
                      <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>



                  <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
                  </select>--->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
                <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="hrDoctor" />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance"><option selected="selected">5</option><option selected="selected">10</option><option selected="selected">15</option><option selected="selected">20</option> </select>

                        <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
                <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\-]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" data-default=""/></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input id="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
        <!---<div class="form-group buttonWidth resetButton"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset"  onClick="window.location.reload()"/></div>--->
    </form>
<!---</div><!---Progress bar--->--->
</div>
```

The problem I am having is when I choose a city after a zip code was entered with the info displayed, the new results for the city selected is not displaying. It appears in the debugging tool, it is still grabbing from the zip field and not sure why.

**Update**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $('#zip').on("input",function(){
    $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);

   })

 $('#city').on("change",function(){
    $('#zip').val("");
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
<!--- <div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background: url('loader.gif') center center #efefef"></div><!--Progress bar--->
  <form name="providerSearch" id="PS" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
            <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

   <div class="form-group">
             <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
        <option value="">Sylmar</option>
          <option value="">Santa Clarita</option>
        <option value="">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="">Ventura</option>
                          <option value=""></option>
       </select>
                      
            <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>---->
            </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
     <div class="form-group widthLanguage">
              
                      
                    <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
      <cfoutput query="Languages">
        <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
                      
                      
       <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
         <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
          </select>--->
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
     <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr class="hrDoctor" />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance">
                          <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>10</option>
                          <option>15</option>
                          <option >20</option>
                          </select>

       <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
     <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\-]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" data-default=""/></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group"><input id="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
   <!---<div class="form-group buttonWidth resetButton"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset"  onClick="window.location.reload()"/></div>--->
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

So using the Chrome developer tool, it appears that the last entry does not get removed using the ready function that I have. It shows the following:

[image]

As you can see on the last line, the new city is recognized but the old zip is replace but the value is still being used rather then being removed

Is it possible to force the search button to remove the old value from zip?

**Here is the code for a placeholder. It is used mainly to fix the issue for IE 9 and below**.

It works fine but I am not sure if this is causing the issue where the zip field is not being recognize that it is blank.

```
    (function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
        var $target = label.data('target');
        if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

I appreciate for all the help I have been receiving, I appreciate it

Comment: Can you post workable code with proper values? So that it becomes clear as to what you have to clear and what is your problem.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati I have posted code I am working on. So the issue is that when a the field city is selected and prior to the selection, a zip code was entered, instead of displaying data from the entry from the city field, it returns the same value from the zip code that was blanked out.

Comment: You mean to say on click of Search button you are getting old zip code value instead of the city that you have selected, right? In that case can you let me know what code you are using to get that value?

Comment: @DineshPrajapati Correct, that is what I mean. For you second question, not sure where the other developer put that code where it gets the value. Have not been able to find the file nor been able to reach him.

Comment: Certainly the problem seems to be within that code where actually you are retrieving the value from the city dropdown or zipcode text box.

Comment: It might be. But when I use the developer tool on chrome, I notice that if I manually delete the zip code field and then select a city, it works.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati I know this is a noob question (which I am) but is their a way to force the search button to remove the old zip value when a city is selected in the drop down box?

Comment: I have a question: could it be possible that the placeholder is causing the search button to think the field is not blank?

Comment: That depends on how you are accessing that value in code and what condition you are using to consider it as empty. Please post that part of the code. Where you are actually fetching the value.